# How to point external domain to a subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ip, cname-record, a-record

I have the domain `example.com` and have set up the Ubuntu Apache server in a way that it points any subdomain to a directory with the same name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

So `subdomain.example.com` will point to `example.com/subdomain`.

I am trying to allow users point their own custom domain to a subdomain of their choice, how could I achieve this and what records would be required and what would have to be done to the **Virtual Host**?

I have tried the following record:

- `sampledomain.example` (**CNAME** record) - `@` --> `sample.example.com`
- `sampledomain.example` **(A** record) - `@` --> (`IP` Address of example.com)

I have also tried using `www` for the CNAME along with removing the `A record`.

`sample.example.com` successfully points to `example.com/sample`. However, `sampledomain.example` acts like the root site for some reason.

So if I visit `sampledomain.example/sample`, I will get the contents of `example.com/sample` rather than pointing to `sample.example.com`.

How could I sort this out? Which records would be needed and what could be done to the Virtual Host?

I used a CNAME record so that I can retrieve the custom domain name via PHP when the user visits that - is the CNAME required?

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with doing this manually on request for your customer, this is easy. All you have to do is to add `ServerAlias sampledomain.com` to the vhost configuration and reload the web server config.

However, if you want to have your customers doing this themselves in some kind of customer control interface, this is not easily achievable due to the way virtual hosts on a web server work. Here is why:

If you have any DNS record (regardless if `A` or `CNAME`) mapping `sampledomain.com` to your web server, the browser will send a request to your servers IP address with the HTTP `Host` header set to `sampledomain.com`. The web server will use this header to decide which virtual host is supposed to handle this and if `sampledomain.com` is neither a vhost name nor alias, the request will be answered by the default vhost as you have experienced.

To make this possible, you need a way for your customers to configure aliases for their vhost. With Apache, this is not easy but in theory you can read this from a database, as explained [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ApacheVirtualHostMysql) (I've never tried this, so I've no clue if this works).

Also, things like [VirtualMin](http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html) might be helpful in such a case.